# lapply and invalid 'description' argument

Tags: r, arguments, lapply

I have a directory with 144 files (.bed).

I would like to analyze them with a function from a R package (ChAseR). To avoid a for loop, I decided to use a lapply function.

```
# Define path

setwd("/home/works/Project/")
netpath="Table"
bedpath="Data/Naive_CD4_positive_T_Cells_BP/H3K27ac/bed_files"

# PCHiC contact network data loading and preprocessing
pchic=read.table(paste(netpath, "merged_samples_12Apr2015_full.txt", sep="/"), sep="\t", skip=4, header=T)

pchic[,1]=paste('chr', pchic[,1], sep='')

pchic[,6]=paste('chr', pchic[,6], sep='')

Tcellnaive <- pchic[which(pchic$Naive_CD4>=5),c(1,2,3,6,7,8)]

tnet=chaser::make_chromnet(Tcellnaive)

# Load histone modifications data from Chen et al. 2016 (doi: 10.1016/j.cell.2016.10.026)
files <- list.files(path=bedpath, pattern="*.bed", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
tnet2 <- lapply(files, chaser::load_features(tnet, files, type="macs2", missingv=0, featnames="H3K27ac"))
```

I obtained this message:

```
 reading from file Data/Naive_CD4_positive_T_Cells_BP/H3K27ac/bed_files/S01342H2.H3K27ac.ppqt_macs2_wp10.20150819.bed...
 reading from file Data/Naive_CD4_positive_T_Cells_BP/H3K27ac/bed_files/S0137XH3.H3K27ac.ppqt_macs2_wp10.20150819.bed...
 reading from file Data/Naive_CD4_positive_T_Cells_BP/H3K27ac/bed_files/S013CNH3.H3K27ac.ppqt_macs2_wp10.20150819.bed...
 reading from file Data/Naive_CD4_positive_T_Cells_BP/H3K27ac/bed_files/S013DLH2.H3K27ac.ppqt_macs2_wp10.20150819.bed...
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

How to resolve this error? Maybe a problem with the path or the function?

Comment: It seems like the error pops up half part way through for a particular file. My guess is  there's a problem in that file - you should inspect it.

Comment: I did a for loop and that worked. Think, the iteration doesn't apply very well with lapply and I don't know how to correct that.

```
for (i in files) {
  tnet <- chaser::load_features(tnet, i, type="macs2", missingv=0, featnames="H3K27ac")
}
```